# Opening, reading, and writing to a serial port in the Windows kernel

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, kernel, device-driver

I'm writing a Windows kernel driver in C and I need to send and receive data over a serial device, specifically COM3. I am stuck on the CreateFile, ReadFile, and WriteFile functions, as these seem to be user space functions that will not work in the kernel. Am I mistaken? Or if not, what is the best way to open and use a serial port from within the Windows kernel?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [ZwCreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ZwReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ZwWriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions for working in kernel mode.

Answer (score -1):

You are writing a driver then You must have to write kernel module for windows .

check this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-1-Introduction-to-Drivers

One more thing once you have finished the driver you need a application to test it.

so  you need a user space application to test it.

Comment: I know, I am writing a kernel module. I know what a driver is and I already have a means by which to test this driver in userspace. I appreciate the response, though.